# Generate URLs for images hosted on Google Drive

Tags: vb.net, url, google-drive

The brief is to be able to generate links to artwork files and PDFs easily and quickly without having to use a browser.

I have added an image box which shows the user the image upon clicking one. The links are taken from a dir listing in Google Drive. There is then some conversion to change the folder location to the Google Drive URL.

I would love a review and any pointers to better ways to do this.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim FolderDriveList() As String
    Dim FolderWebList() As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Load base data into Listbox1
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("AppName.Products.txt"))
            MyArray = Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), vbLf)
        End Using
        ListBox1.DataSource = MyArray
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("AppName.GoogleDriveLinks.txt"))
            FolderDriveList = Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), vbLf)
        End Using
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("AppName.GoogleDriveWebLinks.txt"))
            FolderWebList = Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), vbLf)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
        'Select item in list, update image if preview is enabled
        Dim SelectedFile As String, X As Long
        SelectedFile = TextBox2.Text
        For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
            SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
        Next
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ImagePreview, SelectedFile)
        Else
            ImagePreview.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        'Turn the image preview on and off
        Dim SelectedFile As String, X As Long
        SelectedFile = TextBox2.Text
        For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
            SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
        Next
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ImagePreview, SelectedFile)
        Else
            ImagePreview.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
        'Push SelectedFile across to the Link List Box
        Dim SelectedFile As String, X As Long
        SelectedFile = TextBox2.Text
        For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
            SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
        Next
        ListBox2.Items.Add(SelectedFile)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox2_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.DoubleClick
        'Remove Selected Item from Copy List
        ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Populate Textbox2 with single item when selected from Listbox1
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Copy single item from Textbox2 to clipboard
        Dim SelectedFile As String, X As Long
        SelectedFile = TextBox2.Text
        For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
            SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
        Next
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetText(SelectedFile)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Copy all items from Listbox2 to clipboard
        Dim CopyString As String
        CopyString = ""
        For Each ListBoxLine As Object In ListBox2.Items
            CopyString = CopyString & ListBoxLine.ToString & vbLf
        Next
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetText(CopyString)
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        'Update Listbox1 from Textbox1 (using for filtering)
        Dim FilteredArray(0) As String
        Dim ProdName As String
        Dim X As Long = 0
        ListBox1.DataSource = MyArray
        For Each ProdName In ListBox1.Items
            If InStr(UCase(ProdName), UCase(TextBox1.Text)) > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve FilteredArray(X)
                FilteredArray(X) = ProdName
                X = X + 1
            End If
        Next
        ListBox1.DataSource = FilteredArray
    End Sub

    Public Function LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ByVal pb As PictureBox, ByVal ImageURL As String) As Boolean
        'Load preview image
        Dim objImage As MemoryStream
        Dim objwebClient As WebClient
        Dim sURL As String = Trim(ImageURL)
        Dim bAns As Boolean
        Try
            objwebClient = New WebClient()
            objwebClient.Proxy = Nothing
            objImage = New  _
               MemoryStream(objwebClient.DownloadData(sURL))
            pb.Image = Image.FromStream(objImage)
            bAns = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            bAns = False
        End Try
        Return bAns
    End Function
End Class
```

Sample Data:

Products.txt:

> ```
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BowralBricks-NAT.jpg
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BowralBricks-NAT.pdf
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BrickBrochure-NSW.jpg
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BrickBrochure-NSW.pdf
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BrickBrochure-QLD.jpg
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BrickBrochure-QLD.pdf
> brochures\australbricks\AB-Bricks-BrickBrochure-SA.jpg
> ```

GoogleDriveLinks.txt:

> ```
> brochures\australbricks\
> brochures\australmasonry\CASESTUDIES\
> brochures\australmasonry\CMAA\
> brochures\australmasonry\SALE\
> brochures\australmasonry\
> brochures\australpavers\
> brochures\australprecast\
> brochures\auswesttimbers\
> ```

GoogleDriveWebLinks:

> ```
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_ZDRneURkdXprcEk
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_Z3hGSzVvdjVXcGs
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_UnFyRUxyX0FrMXM
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_NFVBRzZ4MHZGN0E
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_WHpsWUlidWVCdXM
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_SHZzNUZtdGNlZlE
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_WmRWVXpqRzVPbnM
> https://googledrive.com/host/0B-ZYtyWU3Ek_d3hFUmpZV2RHaTA
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all I would like to give you some general hints for refactoring your code for better code quality (in my opinion):

   - Name your variables in a meaningful way - also the controls: `Button1` isn't a good name.
   - When declaring and also instantiating  a variable the `Type =` is superfluous: `Dim sr as new StreamReader` instead of `Dim sr as StreamReader = new StreamReader`
   - Better use method names instead of comments
   - Try to extract code pieces to methods instead of doing serveral things in one EventHandler.

Your `Form1_Load`-Method could look like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadBaseDataIntoListbox1()
    LoadFolderDriveList()
    LoadFolderWebList()
End Sub
```

- Try not to have copies of snippets in your code. Again: Try to extract methods:

The following code is found several times in you project:

```
For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
        SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
Next

If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ImagePreview, SelectedFile)
Else
    ImagePreview.Image = Nothing
End If
```

Also I have some suggestions for improvement of this Method:

```
'This is VB6 style
'For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
'    SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
'Next

'Use this instead:
For i = 0 To FolderDriveList.Length - 1
    SelectedFile = SelectedFile.Replace(FolderDriveList(i).Trim, FolderWebList(i).Trim & "/")
Next
```

For loading text from resources I personally would prefer to use Resources instead of the hard coded Resource-Name:

```
Private Sub LoadBaseDataIntoListbox1()

    Using sr As New StringReader(My.Resources.Resource.Products)

        'I recommend not to use VB6-Like syntax:
        '   String.Split(separator) instead of Split(String, separator)
        '   Environment.NewLine insetad of old VisualBasic constant vblf
        Products = sr.ReadToEnd.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    End Using

    ProductsBox.DataSource = Products
End Sub
```

Always use `using` when using Disposable objects you do not need afterwards:

```
Public Function LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ByVal pb As PictureBox, ByVal ImageURL As String) As Boolean
    'Load preview image
    Try
        Using objwebClient As New WebClient()
            objwebClient.Proxy = Nothing

            Dim sURL As String = ImageURL.Trim
            Using objImage As New MemoryStream(objwebClient.DownloadData(sURL))

                pb.Image = Image.FromStream(objImage)
            End Using
        End Using

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

2. Now to the functionality of the loading process:

What are you trying to do with this code snippet?

```
For X = LBound(FolderDriveList) To UBound(FolderDriveList)
    SelectedFile = Replace(SelectedFile, FolderDriveList(X).Trim, FolderWebList(X).Trim & "/")
Next
```

It would be helpful, if you could give us an example of the content of your resource lists.

I think it would be nice to create a new class which represents an object with the different link types.
You would be able to bind a list of those objects to your controls and define which Property (link type) to display.

Comment: What I would love this thing to do is read the JPG and PDF contents of the site at run time and do away with all 3 text file objects but I don't think i can poll a site for a list of files and I don't think Code Review is the place for me to start collaborating on such a change.

Comment: Now I understand what the goal of your post was. Yes, this is not the right place to ask this I think.
A little hint: Maybe the Google Drive API is what you are looking for.
[link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)